# Connecting lost during importing large data

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to import large data table, around 1 billion record into MySQL(Amazon RDS) with a single `.sql` file by using `source <.sql file>`. During operation it is breaking connection.

How can I make it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Split into smaller sets and load those.

Comment: my mysql client is dumping into a single SQL file, are you suggesting I manually create SQL files?

Comment: In this case write an exporter (split by key range for example), or a tiny program which just selects from 1 db per x (several thousands of records) and inserts in the amazon db using batch statements (When you have to write export code, writing the import code is just another 10 minutes work)

Comment: **Please show the exact error.**  This is commonly caused by a misconfiguration of `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I could not preserve the error but `max_allowed_packet` currently is `4194304`

Comment: It's currently 4194304 where?  That's the thing -- there are two different parameters, one on the client, one on the server, with the same name but not actually correlated.  `SELECT @@MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET;`, then take that value and use `mysql --max_allowed_packet=nnnn < dumpfile.sql` with the same number.  This should cause a clearer error message to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to import the data into a mysql database locally, shut down the database server, then use import it into an amazon EC2 instance, then use replication to synchronize it to RDS. This is from the Amazon documentation on [importing a large database to RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html).

Comment: I guess I am already doing it, I have an EC2 instance using to connect with RDS on other  machine and then I tried `source <filename>` within EC2 instance